# Generate PDF dynamically in Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Which of the following is the best way of generating pdf in java using iText:

1. Generate pdf from scratch each time.
2. Have a predefined pdf, and each time push the data values to the predefined pdf and save as new pdf.
3. Generate a XML each time from the data to be pushed and generate a new pdf each time.

Appreciate your response.

Comment: Each has advantages and disadvantages. Unfortunately broad questions like this are not on-topic for SO. You'll need to reform your question to post a specific query with an objective solution.

Comment: Can you add some more background to the problem, as it is to broad at the moment.

Comment: To elaborate more of my question - I have a UI where the user will fill First name, Last name, Address and so on. After clicking on the save button i need to generate a PDF with the details of first name, last name, address and so on. Which option you think it will suit to my requirement

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218444/generate-and-design-pdf-with-itextsharp-or-similar

Answer (score 2):

1. When you have the PDF Generating code `GENERIC to appending data and making STYLING and TRANSFORMATIONS to the DYNAMIC CONTENT`, it is advised to pass your data to that and `GENERATE from the SCRATCH`.
2. If you are `adding IMAGES, STYLING and TRANSFORMATIONS to the STATIC CONTENT`, it is better to make a `PREDEFINED PDF with DATA-HOTSPOT-ID`s so that you can `REPLACE those IDs with your DYNAMIC CONTENT`.

Comment: Looks like a good answer but did you intend to format those parts as bold-cap?

Comment: Yes, I mean to say that those are very few factors which are relevant to the solution I have given. Much more factors may diverge the solution.

Comment: To elaborate more of my question - I have a UI where the user will fill First name, Last name, Address and so on. After clicking on the save button i need to generate a PDF with the details of first name, last name, address and so on. Which option you think it will suit to my requirement.

Comment: @user1457957 See **Option 2** of my answer to [Generate and design PDF with iTextSharp or similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218444/generate-and-design-pdf-with-itextsharp-or-similar) and please read [the documentation](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) before asking questions that are asking to be closed.